# ChartJS doesn't read data unless I am debugging

Tags: javascript, chart.js

My chart doesn't read my array data unless I hit breakpoints while obtaining the data through JSON url. If I am debugging, my chart renders okay, if not, it's blank. Please help. Thank you!

```
<script>
var labels = [];
var payments = [];

jQuery.getJSON("<?=base_url()?>Admin/getJSONWeeklyDates", function(data) {
    labels = data;
    });
jQuery.getJSON("<?=base_url()?>Admin/getJSONWeeklyPayments", function(data) {
    payments = data;
}); 

</script> 

<script>
( function ( $ ) {
"use strict";

// single bar chart
var ctx = document.getElementById( "singelBarChart" );
ctx.height = 150;
var myChart = new Chart( ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Payments",
                data: payments,
                borderColor: "rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.9)",
                borderWidth: "0",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5)"
                        }
                    ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [ {
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
                            } ]
        }
    }
} );
} )( jQuery );
</script>
```

Note: When I console log the labels' and payments' array length it shows 0 even though it has 2 values when I access the array through console after page load.

Comment: Your `.getJSON()` calls are **asynchronous**. The calls return immediately without waiting for the underlying HTTP requests to return the response content. You've already asked a very similar question to this one!

Comment: Oh yeah. My bad. I did not quite understand the concept of asynchronous calls then. My page this time had numerous JSON calls therefore I did not realize immediately what was happening until you raised it. Thanks